# Where to add event handlers

Tags: ios, uitableview

It appears there are multiple places to add event handlers for targets. Currently I have a slider in a `UITableViewCell` with multiple methods hooked up to control events: `UIControlEventValueChanged`, `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` and `UIControlEventTouchUpOutside`.

These are added currently added within the `layoutSubviews` method, but I'm not sure if that is the right place. I tried moving them to the UITableViewController (as in I add them in the `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method), but now I'm not sure what the correct place is to add these things.

Should I keep them in the `layoutSubviews` (which is called repeatedly over time, because of scrolling, not sure what this does to the event handlers, do they get added multiple times?), move it to the `initWithStyle` (also not sure about this one, I tried an NSLog in this method, but it wasn't called even once), or put it in the UITableViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `layoutSubviews` method is definitely *not* the right place: it is there for controlling the layout, not to hook up event handlers - not to mention a possibility of hooking up the same handler multiple times!

The right place to add events to standard cells is the `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. For custom cells drawn using Interface Builder you should be able to connect the events visually.

Answer (score 1):

You should add them when the slider is created. If the slider is created in an XIB then you should really add the connection there too, otherwise you would add it in `viewDidLoad` or, depending on your construction, `awakeFromNib`. If the slider is created in code then add them immediately after the creation.